# How to identify the pool member that processed an HTTP_REQUEST in an iRule

Tags: big-ip

To help with diagnosing a production issue, I'd like to insert the name of the pool member that handled the HTTP_RESPONSE.

I have a pool (my_application_pool) configured with three members (WEB1, WEB2, WEB3), like this:

- Pool: my_application_pool

  - Pool Member: WEB1
  - Pool Member: WEB2
  - Pool Member: WEB3

I have an iRule that looks like this:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
      pool my_application_pool
}

when HTTP_RESPONSE {
      HTTP::header insert pool_member_name value_1
}
```

If it is WEB2 that processed a request, how can I replace "value_1" with "WEB2"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your irule above to populate value_1:

```
when LB_SELECTED {
  set value_1 [LB::server addr]
}
```

If you are using multiple ports with same addr and/or route domains, you can expand that to be:

```
set value_1 "[LB::server addr]%[LB::server route_domain]:[LB::server port]"
```

Comment: Thanks! Assuming this works, it's no wonder I didn't find the answer! I'll go give this a try...

Comment: I'm not smart enough to know what "route domains" are, so maybe that is why the second example only returned a %:8080 -- other than that, your answer got me something that works. Thanks!